# powershell replace with regex any char except '.'

Tags: regex, powershell

I try to replace "..\..\..\..\[AnyCharacters]"

to

"..\..\..\..\.."

with regex in powershell.

I tried many patterns, but problem is the same, that it always starts from the begining of string and it changes all instead of last `[AnyCharacters]`. 
There could be more backslashes with dots. I do not know how many exactly.

Comment: There is no reason to replace fixed strings with regex. The .NET string replace `"..\..\bla".Replace("..\", "")` will do just fine.

Comment: @Tomalak Except if you get a string `c:\something\..\autoexec.bat` of course. But the meaning is changed for the original path in the question as well. With that in mind, just asking the FS API for an absolute path might be a better idea.

Comment: [What is the X Y problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  Tell us about X, not Y.

Comment: @Maarten The OP has not clarified what they actually are after, so all I"m going on is *"how to remove dot-dot-backslash from a string"*.

Comment: please show us the code you have tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i suspect that i have misunderstood  your intent. however, if you really want to simply replace the final text with two dots, then this will work. it uses the builtin path  handling cmdlets to do the work ... [*grin*]

```
$PathString = '..\..\..\..\AnyThingHere.txt'
$DotDot = '..'

Join-Path -Path (Split-Path -Path $PathString -Parent) -ChildPath $DotDot
```

output = `..\..\..\..\..`